# Opportunity Product in Lightning - Advice, please

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am using Lightning and its standard functionality of adding products on an opportunity. I need when the users are selecting the products from **Add Products** page and click Next; On the **Edit Selected Products**, a field to show or hide depending on the product type selected previously. I have created the field on the Opportunity Line Item - a Lookup field to the custom object (not ideal).

This is what I have built so far, but it's not working:

```
<aura:component >
    <aura:attribute name="ProductType" type="String" default="ProductType1" />
     <aura: attribute name ="Customfield" type="String" />

    <lightning:select name="ProductName" value="{! v.ProductType}">
         <option value = "ProductType1">ProductType1</option>
         <option value = "ProductType2">ProductType2</option>
         <option value = "ProductType3">ProductType3</option>
         <option value = "ProductType4">ProductType4</option>

    </lightning:select>


    <aura:if isTrue="{! v.AdType == 'ProductType5' }">

        <lightning:input label="Customfield" value ="{! v.Customfield}" />

    </aura:if>
</aura:component>
```

*Where ProductType 5 is the type of product, the custom field (lookup field doesn't need to show on the OLI.

If anyone has a bit of time and can provide some help, that would be great.

Thanks a lot in advance.

S

Comment: Hi SSimon , Welcome to SFSE, You have too many problems statements in this big post. Can you target the specifics? Also, its fine to create multiple questions to target specific problem.

Comment: Hi,Thank you. Yes sure.

Answer (score 0):

You have `lightning:select` , whenever you select a value in it, it gets binded to `value="{!v.ProductType}`

So you have to check that in your `aura:if`. If productType!="ProductType5" then show your lightning:input

```
<aura:attribute type="String" name="ProductType"></aura:attribute>
    <aura:attribute type="String" name="Customfield"></aura:attribute>


    <lightning:select name="ProductName" value="{! v.ProductType}" label="productName">
        <option value = "ProductType1">ProductType1</option> 
        <option value = "ProductType2">ProductType2</option>
        <option value = "ProductType3">ProductType3</option>
        <option value = "ProductType4">ProductType4</option>
        <option value = "ProductType5">ProductType5 </option>

    </lightning:select>


    <aura:if isTrue="{! v.ProductType != 'ProductType5' }">

        <lightning:input label="Customfield" value ="{! v.Customfield}" />

    </aura:if>
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much for your reply. I am trying to save this applying all the changes suggested but I am getting this error message - 1,52: Invalid attribute "type": Source. It fails to save. Is it because ProductType is a pick-list field that contains all the types of products?

Comment: create a new aura app from dev console. Post the above code snippet and try if it works?

Comment: Hi, I have managed to save the code by creating a new aura, as you suggested, but unfortunately doesn't hide the field for a type of product. Do I need a trigger for this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: It does for ProductType5?

Comment: The custom field appears for all ProductTypes, I am afraid. Thanks for your patience. And I want to be able to hide the custom field for one of the producttypes.